# Dataframe column based in columns conditions

Tags: python, pandas

```
     a    b
0  100   90
1   30  117
2   90   99
3  200   94
```

I want to create a new `df["c"]` with next conditions:

- If *b* is into *(a ± 0.5a)* then *c = a*
- If *b* is out *(a ± 0.5a)* then *c = b*

Output should be:

```
     a    b    c
0  100   90  100
1   30  117  117
2   90   99   90
3  200   94   94
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with conditions created by [`eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) or chained conditions with `&` or [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df['c'] = np.where(df.eval("0.5 * a <= b <= 1.5 * a"), df.a, df.b)
#alternative 1
#df['c'] = np.where((df['b'] >= df.a.mul(1.5)) & (df['b'] <= df.a.mul(0.5)), df.a, df.b)
#alternative 2
#df['c'] =  np.where(df['b'].between(df.a.mul(0.5), df.a.mul(1.5)), df.a, df.b)

print (df)
     a    b    c
0  100   90  100
1   30  117  117
2   90   99   90
3  200   94   94
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need `where` here , also you two condition is can be treat as one , so we only need one time if--else (which is `where`) logic here

```
df['c']=df['a']
df.c=df.c.where((df.a*1.5>df.b)&(df.a*0.5<df.b),df.b)
df
Out[746]: 
     a    b    c
0  100   90  100
1   30  117  117
2   90   99   90
3  200   94   94
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way using [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) accessor and [`pd.Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html).

```
df['c'] = df['b']

df.loc[df['b'].between(0.5*df['a'], 1.5*df['a']), 'c'] = df['a']
```

**Result**

```
     a    b    c
0  100   90  100
1   30  117  117
2   90   99   90
3  200   94   94
```

**Explanation**

- Set a default value for the series.
- Update using `.loc` for your specific criterion.
- If you have *further* conditions, you can switch to using `numpy.where` as per other answers.